# aggregating data from different column

Tags: r

how do I turn this dataframe

```
city2001 <- c('a', 'b', 'a')
grade2001 <- c(5, 5, 7)
city2002 <- c('b', 'b', 'a')
grade2002 <- c(8, 9, 10)

df <- data.frame(city2001, grade2001, city2002, grade2002)
```

into a data frame that looks like this:

```
| city | grade  |
|:---- |:------:|
| a    | 5      |
| b    | 5      |
| a    | 7      |
| b    | 8      |
| b    | 9      |
| a    | 10     |

thanks!
```

Comment: Some of the answers to your previous question do that. For instance,  @onyambu's answer: `library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c('.value', 'year'),
                  names_pattern = '(\\D+)(\\d+)') `

Comment: Yet another possibility, which comes from my answer to your previous question: `library(tidyverse)

map_dfr(list(df[1:2], df[3:4]), ~ \`colnames<-\`(.x, c("city", "grade")))`

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to your last question, but not exactly since you are trying to melt the data frame and keep the original values. A similar solution to the previous:

```
data.frame(
  "city"=unlist(df[,grepl("city",colnames(df))]),
  "grade"=unlist(df[,grepl("grade",colnames(df))])
)

          city grade
city20011    a     5
city20012    b     5
city20013    a     7
city20021    b     8
city20022    b     9
city20023    a    10
```

Comment: thanks, and how do I get the standard deviation let say, for city b from this table? I am new to R